# How to detect ctrl-f in my SWT application

Tags: java, event-handling, keyboard-shortcuts, swt

I have written an SWT UI which has a primary function of displaying text in a StyledText control. I want to add a handler for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> so that when that shortcut is pressed the focus is set to a search box. I have tried using the following code to detect the keypress.

```
sWindow = new Shell();
...
sWindow.getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener()
{
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event e)
  {
    System.out.println("Filter-ctrl: " + SWT.CTRL);
    System.out.println("Filter-mask: " + e.stateMask);
    System.out.println("Filter-char: " + e.character);
  }
});
```

I was expecting that when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> I would see the following output:

```
Filter-ctrl: 262144
Filter-mask: 262144
Filter-char: f
```

However, in practice I actually see the following.

```
Filter-ctrl: 262144
Filter-mask: 262144
Filter-char: <unprintable char - displayed as a box in eclipse console>
```

I have two questions:

- Is Display.addFilter(...) the best way to add a global shortcut? I tried Display.addListener(...) but this didn't receive any events at all.
- Why don't I get the pressed character when I'm holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>? When I hold down alt or shift I get the expected mask and the pressed character.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

***`Is Display.addFilter(...) the best way to add a glbal shortcut? I tried Display.addListener(...) but this didn't receive any events at all.`***

Yes, normally `Display.addFilter(...)` is the best way to add a glbal shortcut because they have higher preference over the event listeners. See the below comment from `Display.addFilter(...)` javadoc.

> Because event filters run before other
>   listeners, event filters can both
>   block other listeners and set
>   arbitrary fields within an event. For
>   this reason, event filters are both
>   powerful and dangerous. They should
>   generally be avoided for performance,
>   debugging and code maintenance
>   reasons.

---

**For your second question:**

***`Why don't I get the pressed character when I'm holding down ctrl? When I hold down alt or shift I get the expected mask and the pressed character.`***

The problem is that you are looking at the wrong place. Instead of querying `e.character` you should be using `e.keyCode`. As per javadoc of `e.character` you won't get just character `f`:

> Depending on the event, the character
>   represented by the key that was typed.
>   This is the final character that
>   results after all modifiers have been
>   applied. For example, when the user
>   types Ctrl+A, the character value is
>   0x01 (ASCII SOH).

So when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> then it converts in `0x06` (ASCII ACK). Which is not the case when you do <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> **or** <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.

On the other hand the javadoc of `e.keyCode` says:

> depending on the event, the key code
>   of the key that was typed, as defined
>   by the key code constants in class
>   SWT. When the character field of the
>   event is ambiguous, this field
>   contains the unaffected value of the
>   original character. For example,
>   typing Ctrl+M or Enter both result in
>   the character '\r' but the keyCode
>   field will also contain '\r' when
>   Enter was typed and 'm' when Ctrl+M
>   was typed.

Check the below code for more details. For demo I have tried to put listener on `Display` and `Test`.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ControlF 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Display display = new Display ();

        final Shell shell = new Shell (display);
        final Color green = display.getSystemColor (SWT.COLOR_GREEN);
        final Color orig = shell.getBackground();

        display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                if(((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL) && (e.keyCode == 'f'))
                {
                    System.out.println("From Display I am the Key down !!" + e.keyCode);
                }
            }
        });

        shell.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if(((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL) && (e.keyCode == 'f'))
                {
                    shell.setBackground(orig);
                    System.out.println("Key up !!");
                }
            }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL) && (e.keyCode == 'f'))
                {
                    shell.setBackground(green);
                    System.out.println("Key down !!");
                }
            }
        });

        shell.setSize (200, 200);
        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();

    }
}
```

Comment: This was an excellent answer - I have now got my shortcut working. Thanks! I'll try to read the docs better myself next time!

Comment: how can we override system shortcut like ctrl+c by adding a filter like this?

Comment: @Fahad - Suggest you to ask it as a separate question.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842190/how-to-detect-ctrl-f-in-my-swt-application

Comment: Note: For Mac's you'll want to include cases for the SWT.COMMAND key event if you want to consider the command+<key> events.