# SWT.KeyUp triggers too often

Tags: java, swt, keylistener

I've some trouble to understand the key event in SWT. My program runs under Windows 8.1 + Java 8.
For example I have a text field and try to handle KeyUp:

```
textField.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event e) {
  }
});
```

In the handleEvent method I set e.doit to false and then I try to differ between the arrow keys, the space key or some combinations of ALT + letter etc.

I'm wondering a bit because my application executes not the right tasks. So I debugged the coe and found out that the handleEvent method is executing three times with different event object each time.
That's not good beacause in this case it's almost impossible to make it work in the expected way - each call could replace f.e. attribute values of the previous call.
And I don't know the reason: I press one key and the handler method is called three times. Why? It's a little bit illogical for me...

+++ EDITED +++

```
package mytest;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class Main {
  private static int i = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Text textField = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.SINGLE);
    textField.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener() {
      @Override
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        e.doit = false;
        System.out.println("Call #" + (++i) + ": keyCode=" + e.keyCode);
      }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

You can run this little example and then press f.e. ALT+A, CTRL+I or ARROW_DOWN and you will see that the handle method is called very often per press and this is not what I'm expecting from a key listener!

Comment: That is not what I see doing a quick test. You need to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok, I posted a little code example to demonstrate the problem; please keep in mind that I'm running it under Windows.

Comment: On my Mac I see two events which is what I would expect - one for each of the keys being released.

Comment: @greg: No. For example if I press CTRL+o then I will expect to find SWT.CTRL in e.stateMask and 'o' char in e.keyCode in the same event object. That's why I expect one call of the handler method, not two or threee or so on. Otherwise I have to combine the key codes of each method call in a global variable to get the complete shortcut and that would be curious.

Comment: If my answer does not match your expectations, please provide exact output that you are seeing and what the input is. It was very useful to provide a [MCVE] bit of code, next to be explicit on inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

What you want to observe is the other fields in the event:

[stateMask](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/KeyEvent.html#stateMask):

> the state of the keyboard modifier keys and mouse masks at the time
>   the event was generated.

[keyLocation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/KeyEvent.html#keyLocation):

> depending on the event, the location of key specified by the keyCode
>   or character. The possible values for this field are SWT.LEFT,
>   SWT.RIGHT, SWT.KEYPAD, or SWT.NONE representing the main keyboard
>   area.
>
> The location field can be used to differentiate key events that
>   have the same key code and character but are generated by different
>   keys on the keyboard. For example, a key down event with the key code
>   equal to SWT.SHIFT can be generated by the left and the right shift
>   keys on the keyboard.
>
> The location field can only be used to determine the location of the
>   key code or character in the current event. It does not include
>   information about the location of modifiers in the state mask.

### Updated Example

The correct, expected behaviour is as each key is released you get notification. Replace your println in your question with:

```
System.out.println("Call #" + (++i) + ": keyCode=" + e.keyCode + " stateMask=" + e.stateMask
        + " ctrlPressed=" + ((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) != 0) + " shiftPressed="
                + ((e.stateMask & SWT.SHIFT) != 0)+ " altPressed="
                        + ((e.stateMask & SWT.ALT) != 0));
```

and you should observe the correct behaviour. The `stateMask` details the state (e.g. control key pressed).

With your code updated with the extra prints, this is what you see in the console:

for <kbd>a</kbd>:

```
Call #11: keyCode=97 stateMask=0 ctrlPressed=false shiftPressed=false altPressed=false
```

For <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, with <kbd>a</kbd> released first:

```
Call #14: keyCode=97 stateMask=262144 ctrlPressed=true shiftPressed=false altPressed=false
Call #15: keyCode=262144 stateMask=262144 ctrlPressed=true shiftPressed=false altPressed=false
```

For <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> released first:

```
Call #16: keyCode=262144 stateMask=262144 ctrlPressed=true shiftPressed=false altPressed=false
Call #17: keyCode=97 stateMask=0 ctrlPressed=false shiftPressed=false altPressed=false
```

For <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, with <kbd>a</kbd> released first:

```
Call #19: keyCode=97 stateMask=458752 ctrlPressed=true shiftPressed=true altPressed=true
Call #20: keyCode=65536 stateMask=458752 ctrlPressed=true shiftPressed=true altPressed=true
Call #21: keyCode=131072 stateMask=393216 ctrlPressed=true shiftPressed=true altPressed=false
Call #22: keyCode=262144 stateMask=262144 ctrlPressed=true shiftPressed=false altPressed=false
```

### Why?

There are lots of places where you want to know if just the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is pressed and/or released. Consider hovering over a method or variable in Eclipse and pressing/releasing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

### Update

Based on additional information provided in the comments, the OP wants to allow users to create accelerators.

jface, the layer on top of SWT has such a class already [KeySequenceText](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/bindings/keys/KeySequenceText.html) (code: [in git](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.jface/src/org/eclipse/jface/bindings/keys/KeySequenceText.java)),

> A wrapper around the SWT text widget that traps literal key presses
>   and converts them into key sequences for display. There are two types
>   of key strokes that are displayed: complete and incomplete. A complete
>   key stroke is one with a natural key, while an incomplete one has no
>   natural key. Incomplete key strokes are only displayed until they are
>   made complete or their component key presses are released.

Obviously I would recommend reusing that instead of spinning a new one. It is just shy of 1000 lines of code that is heavily in use already, so presumably well exercised and (mostly!) bug free.

Since you are using SWT outside of the Eclipse platform, if you do want to take this approach, you can use [jface outside the platform](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace#Using_JFace_outside_the_Eclipse_platform) too.

Comment: Ok, the meaning of the fields keyCode, stateMask and keyLocation is very clear. But what I don't understand is why there can be more than one call of the handler method. In your example you say that it depends on what key is released first but then it's impossible to find out the correct shortcut, isn't it? For example I press Ctrl+a with Ctrl released first. In this case I can never check for Ctrl+a in the first method call. And I don't know whether there will be a second or third call.

Comment: And then there's also the problem that the events "overrides" themselves. I take keyCode and stateMask in the first handler call, think it's the right shortcut and store it in a database - but no, the handler method is called again and again and again and everytime I get (maybe) wrong shortcuts. What I 'm expecting is that I press the keys, the handler method is called once and the event object contains all information I need.

Comment: If you want to know what is pressed, listen to Key Down events too! for example, listen for (key down) keyCode == a and stateMask == alt, when that state hits then on key up event run your event?

Comment: Hm, please correct me if I'm wrong but the count of method calls for keydown is the same like for keyup. So I've still the same problem. Let's say I want to give the user the possibility to change the shortcut for a menu item. So I want to get the pressed (or released) keys and how should I do this if the event method is called so often with different event objects each time?

Comment: Out of curoisity, are you using SWT on its own or using RCP. The reason I ask is RCP solves the keyboard shortcuts / menu key combinations etc for you, i.e. not something you have to reimplement yourself. Of course, you probably have a very good reason for reimplementing this stuff.

Comment: Back to the question at hand, if you want to detect the simple when the user pressed and released Alt-A, then surely you look for KeyUp on A with ctrlPressed=true, i.e. case 14 above. If all this information does not solve your problem I suggest that I don't understand your problem and I recommend asking a whole new one, because your original question seems solved now. i.e. "SWT.KeyUp triggers too often" is not accurate as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: PS See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842190/how-to-detect-ctrl-f-in-my-swt-application] too

Comment: I'm using pure SWT. But to avoid missundestandings: I don't want to execute shortcuts for menu items. I only want to give the user the possibility to change these shortcuts. For that I built a dialog with a text field in which the user presses the desired keys. I combine the keys with e.keyCode | e.stateMask to a new shortcut and apply it to a specific menu item.

Comment: OK, its a non-trivial task, but fortunately someone else has done the work for you if you want to include it: https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.jface/src/org/eclipse/jface/bindings/keys/KeySequenceText.java

Answer (score -2):

Usually listeners added with addListener are called very frequently at every breath almost. For key events , use

```
textField.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() 
{ 
   public void keyPressed( Event e ) 
} );
```

Comment: You do realize that `addKeyListener()` internally just calls `addListener()` for the appropriate events? So there is no difference. [Here's the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.swt/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64/4.3/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.java#Control.addKeyListener%28org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener%29)

Comment: It looks like it uses addListener() internally, but in my experience using swt listeners adding a specific listener was always efficient instead of adding plain Listener

Comment: @svasa IMHO it can make code more readable and less error prone to use typed listeners, but there is fundamentally an extra layer of translation on each event being fired. Of course I prefer readability unless I know (have tested) performance otherwise. And Baz is correct, there is no difference in the *number* of calls.

Comment: @svasa Do you have any data that supports this claim? I can't see why it would be more efficient.