# How to capture the text typed when Ctrl-F is hit on an SWT Java Application

Tags: java, swt

When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> is hit on an **SWT** table app it brings up a search box.  My application is able to detect when the keyboard shortcut is hit, however, I'm having problems capturing the text that is typed in the search field.

This is the how far I have gotten in my attempt to highlight the lines found.  I would like to assign the captured text to my `searchstring` variable.

```java
package stackE;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

public class QuickTableExampleA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "ljames@ubunzeus: ~|0x0480002c\n"
                + "Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build"
                + " Careers - Google Chrome|0x0520000a\n"
                + "Inbox - L. D. James - Mozilla Thunderbird|0x05208736\n";

        String searchstring = "Stack";

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        shell.setSize(700, 500);
        shell.setText("My Table Smipplet");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());


        Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER);

        TableColumn column1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
        TableColumn column2 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);

        column1.setText("Window");
        column2.setText("Window ID");
        column1.setWidth(600);
        column2.setWidth(70);

        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        String[] array = data.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            // System.out.println(array[i]);
            String[] array2 = array[i].split("\\|");
            TableItem newrow = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
            // newrow.setText(new String[] { array2[0], array2[1] });
            newrow.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
            if(array2[0].contains(searchstring))
                newrow.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));
            newrow.setText(new String[] { array2[0], array2[1] });
        }

        table.addListener(SWT.MouseDoubleClick, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event)
            {
                Point pt = new Point(event.x, event.y);
                TableItem item = table.getItem(pt);
                if (item != null)
                {
                    /* Iterate over all columns and check if event is contained */
                    for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
                    {
                        Rectangle rect = item.getBounds(col);
                        if (rect.contains(pt))
                        {
                            System.out.println("The WindowID is" + item.getText(1));

                            /*
                            The following methods are my efforts to remove the
                            current data so that only the new repopulated data
                            will be in the table.
                            */

                            table.removeAll();
                            repopulateTable();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private void repopulateTable() {
                System.out.println("This is a repopulateTable.");
                String[] array = getdata();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    // System.out.println(array[i]);
                    String[] array2 = array[i].split("\\|");
                    TableItem newrow = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
                    newrow.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
                    if(array2[0].contains(searchstring))
                        newrow.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));
                    newrow.setText(new String[] { array2[0], array2[1] });
                }
            }
        });

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // This block will be triggered when CTRL-F is hit
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                if(((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL) && (e.keyCode == 'f'))
                {
                    System.out.println("From Display I am the Key down !!" + e.keyCode);
                }
            }
        });
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
              display.sleep();
          }
          display.dispose();
    }
    public static String[] getdata() {
        String data = "swt table delete records - Google Search - Google Chrome|0x0480002c\n"
                + "javaTools/src/javaTools/QuickTableExampleA.java -"
                + " /home/users/l/j/ljames/workspace - Eclipse|0x05a000aa\n"
                + "SWT Table Filters and Sorting - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome|0x05c002dc\n"
                + "swt java how to delete a range of rows - Google Search - Google Chrome|0x05208736\n";

        String[] array = data.split("\n");
        return array;
    }
}
```

This question [How to detect ctrl-f in my SWT application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5842190/1204365) is about how to detect the keyboard shortcut, which has an answer.

My question is how to input the text that is typed in the box that pops up by default.

Comment: SWT does not have a Search dialog and there is no default action for Ctrl+F, what dialog are you actually seeing?

Comment: @greg-449 Maybe that explains why I can't find any specifications on that.  But it's not an actual dialog.  It just a field that appears at the bottom of all SWT table widgets (that I have created).  It has never been programmed into any of my code.  I just tested creating a GUI without a table.  Ctrl-F doesn't do anything on that GUI.  I also tried to screen capture a visual of the Table GUI with the Cntrl-F search field, but it disappears when I hit the PrintScreen KB shortcut  By the way, it's similar to what appears when you hit CTRL-F on a Chrome Browser.

Comment: That doesn't happen on macOS so it is probably a function of the native table control that SWT uses on your platform and you are unlikely to be able to access it.

Comment: Thanks.  Valuable information.  Now I can look into creating my own input routine, rather than spending so much research trying to find something that doesn't exist.