# Cannot cast from StyledText to JComponent

Tags: java, swing, casting, key-bindings, jcomponent

I have an editor class extending TextEditor and I need to capture Ctrl + right arrow key pressed event for which I am using key bindings. But the problem is I am unable to cast my editor to JComponent and keylistener doesn't allow me to capture a key stroke combination.

I have tried following code so far.

```
JComponent component = (JComponent) getViewer().getTextWidget();
    component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK),"actionMapKey");
    component.getActionMap().put("actionMapKey", new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    });
```

Comment: `StyledText` is a part of swt and `JComponent` is a part of java swings. You cannot cast a `StyledText` to a `JComponent` as `JComponent` is not a superclass of `StyledText`

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way around it because when I use KeyListener event 
    if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_RIGHT && ((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) > 0)){
     System.out.println("world");
    }
e.stateMask is always zero.

Comment: You can use [this KeyListener](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FKeyListener.html). If you are using swt compoments, use them throughout your code. I personally wouldnt suggest mixing swt and swings.

Comment: I have tried using this listener but the problem is e.stateMask is alwyas zero. When I press Ctrl + -> " (e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) != 0 " should be true.

Comment: the `statemask` returning zero always is a bug in SWT. More info [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402547). Switch the key bindings from CTRL to maybe SHIFT or ALT (if that is possible).

Comment: @Ashwin K Kumar Basically I am building an editor and 'ctrl + ->' is the by the default command for word by word navigation. I need to capture that and add my own functionality to it. Do you know of any other possible ways to do that?

Comment: @safarooj you can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5842873/5281406) There he has implemented it for CTRL + F.

Comment: @AshwinKKumar I tried this and it didin't work either. But for some reason state mask works perfectly in the case of key released event.

Comment: @safarooj Weird. I dont know much on SWT, but if it is working in case of key released event, implement your logic there, that should work as the order is keypressed, key typed and key released, so the key release event will follow your key typed event. So your logic should work.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thanks for the help though. 
`public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_RIGHT && ( e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL ) == SWT.CTRL ){
     System.out.println("hello world");
     }   
}`

Comment: "Note that the key-typed event doesn't have key code information, and key-pressed and key-released events don't have key character information" This is from the JavaDoc for [AWT Key Events](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). I guess SWT works the same way too, I couldnt find any documentation for it. If that is the case, then keyCode and stateMask would work only with keyPressed and keyReleased. This might be the reason why it did not work for you.